# I really need a sapling from a single tree

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I'm playing on some server, called SkyBlock. It starts with one tree. the first one dropped one sapling, now that I've planted it and accomplished a whole lot of other stuff, I don't want to cut down the second without having at least one sapling come off of it.

So what I'm asking is, can a tree with all the leaves cut off regrow it's leaves? Can I use bonemeal on a tree stump to make it grow back into a tree?

Comment: When I've played SkyBlock (on local PC), I used to back my world up before cutting down the last tree. There is an unconditional chance you won't get a sapling and will subsequently lose, so I felt I am morally allowed to cheat this little bit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A tree with all leaves cut off cannot regrow its leaves. In fact any leaves that are removed will not be regrown. Also bonemeal will only work on saplings, not on wood nor logs.

The only way to get another sapling is to destroy your second tree. There is a very high chance that your second tree will drop another sapling, and if it doesn't you will be stuck and lose anyways so it's better to find out sooner than later. Just be sure you make a dirt platform surrounding the tree to catch any items that drop as you destroy it - at least two blocks extending out each side from the tree's leaves. Losing one sapling could end up being gg.

Comment: I ended up just cutting it down. Got a single sapling, so my journey continues on :P

Answer (score 6):

No, tree growth is a one time thing, from a sapling. It will never regrow its leaves, and there is no such thing as a tree stump. At that point it's simply a log block sitting on the ground.